# C# Parent Class with interface based properties that can change per subclassed declaration

Tags: c#, interface, properties, subclassing

I've looked around but can't get my head around what I'm trying to do.  I want to create a baseline interface that multiple other classes can be derived from.  No problem.  Then, I want another class that has a property on it of the common interface base, but not guaranteeing which subclassed version of the interface it will be using.  What approach should I use.  Here's some example of what I'm trying to simulate.

```
public interface IBaseline
{
    string CommonToAll { get; }
    int AnotherCommon { get; }

    void CommonFunction();
}
```

Now, deriving new classes from interface IBaseline

```
public class CDerived1 : IBaseline
{
    private string CommonToAll
    { get { return Whatever; }}

    private int AnotherCommon
    { get { reutrn WhateverInt; }}

    public void CommonFunction)
    { // do something with this classes specific elements...  }


    // now, here are some custom things specific to this class
    private string CustomToThisClass;

    private int CustomFunction()
    { // do something }
}

public class CDerived2: IBaseline
{
    private string CommonToAll
    { get { return Whatever; }}

    private int AnotherCommon
    { get { reutrn WhateverInt; }}

    public void CommonFunction)
    { // do something with this classes specific elements...  }

    // again, these are totally different to the second derived class
    private string TotallyDifferent;

    private bool DiffFunction( int anyParm )
    {  // do something different }

}
```

Now, for my confusion to implement.  I want to create a new class that has a field on it that can be of ANY IBaseline structure, but don't know which version at compile time.

```
public class OtherClass
{
   IBaseline GenericInstance;
   ...
   ...

   public void CommonAccessFunction()
   {
      // call the common function that is generic no matter WHAT 
      // subclassed instance is used.
      GenericInstance.CommonFunction();
   }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem here - you can just pass in a `IBaseline` to your `OtherClass` ? Or you want `OtherClass` to *inherently* work with a specific type?

Comment: And please explain what is wrong with your OtherClass declaration? it now contains IBaseline field, which you can assign any of its implementors - either CDerived1 or CDerived2. This is allowed right out of the box. What is wrong here? maybe I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it generic:

```
public class OtherClass<T> where T : IBaseline
{
    public T GenericInstance { get; private set;}

    public OtherClass(T genericInstance)
    {
        this.GenericInstance = genericInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, without ever having such scenario to apply the concept of Generics, it was hard for me to wrap my head around it.  This approach appears to have done it for me.. especially the CASTing issue.  I already had the constructor accepting a parameter of the new type I was expecting to create with, but didn't want to confuse the post if that would have thrown anyone else off.

Comment: Generics are amazing. I use them all the time. Hopefully you'll find places you can use them to really clean up/shorten some code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

why can't you just pass an instance of IBaseLine into OtherClass, either via the constructor (like in the example below) or via a property?

```
public class OtherClass
{
   IBaseline GenericInstance;

   public OtherClass(IBaseline instance)
   {
        GenericInstance=instance;
   }

   public void CommonAccessFunction()
   {
      // call the common function that is generic no matter WHAT 
      // subclassed instance is used.
      GenericInstance.CommonFunction();
   }
}
```

either I'm missing something or your question is not very clear.  It seems that what you want to do is something that standard practice, your implementation of OtherClass doesn't know anything about which implementation of IBaseline it is using, just that it is using some implementation...

Comment: I believe DRapp is looking for a solution where they wouldn't have to cast, etc. in order to use the non-common members of the GenericInstance.